# How to use .then method for promises with mySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I know that mongodb has their own way of handling native promises with no rejection issues but I guess it doesnt work the same here with mysql. Is there anyway I can use .then in mysql? I was able to do it using more callbacks but I would like to use promises to make the solution cleaner or even use async/await if that makes it simpler too. I need to use a callback to jump to my server file, I have all my methods defined in my db file.

Server file:

```
app.get('/api/cows', (req, res) => {
  db.reqMethods.getAll((err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    res.send('Error');
  } else {
    res.send(data);
  }
});
});
```

db file:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'cowlist'
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Connected to MySQL!')
  }
});

// Your Database Queries Here!!

module.exports.reqMethods = {

// GET All Cow Info
  getAll: function (callback) {
        const query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM cows;');
        query.then(data => callback(null, data));
    });
};

// callback solution that I'd like to simplify: 
//   getAll: function (callback) {
//     connection.query('SELECT * FROM cows;', (err, data) => {
//       if (err) {
//         callback(err, null);
//       } else {
//         console.log("DATA: \n", data);
//         callback(null, data);
//       }
//   });
// }
```

Comment: I don't think `connection.query()` returns a promise, so you can't use `.then()`. You could use `new Promise()` to make your own promise, but you still have to use the callback function and call `resolve()` inside it, so it's even more complex than the original code.

Comment: The only reason you would do that is so that `getAll()` could return a promise, and the server file could use `.then()` instead of the callback.

Comment: then why does mongoose.model('Cows', someSchema).find() return a promise for example?

Comment: Because Mongoose designed their API to return promises.

Comment: MySQL Connector is pretty old, it predates promises.

Comment: I think u shouls start using `mysql2` instead of this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by using `mysql2` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2).

So in your `database.js` file, use this method.

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2');
var pool_connection = mysql.createPool({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3306,
    user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    multipleStatements: true
});
pool_connection.getConnection((err) => {
    if (err) console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    else {
        console.log('Connected!')
    }
});
module.exports = pool_connection.promise();
```

And in your models, you require the connection as follows and make use of async-await in a try-catch block.

```js
const con = require('/path/to/your/database_file');
module.exports = class Messages {
    constructor() { }
    static async getMessage(arguments_here) {
        const query = "some query here with params if required. Use ? for placing params and do not use string literal to embed params.";
        try {
            const [response] = await con.execute(query, [params]);
            return response;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And in your controller,

```js
const Messages = require('../models/Messages');

const someFn = async (req, res) =>{
   try {
        const result = await Messages.getMessages('sample_arguments');
    //do something with result
    }
    catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
}
```